# Proving that $f(z)$ being entire in $\mathbb C$ does not imply $f(\bar z)$ being entire

Tags: complex-analysis

My current argument is, if $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C$, then it always has a derivative. Then I calculated the following limits (with $h \in \mathbb R$):

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\overline {z+h})-f(\overline z)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\overline {z}+h)-f(\overline z)}{h}=f'(\overline z)$$

and

$$\lim_{ih\to 0}\frac{f(\overline {z+ih})-f(\overline z)}{ih}=-\lim_{ih\to 0}\frac{f(\overline {z}-ih)-f(\overline z)}{-ih}=-f'(\overline z)$$

I have a feeling I might be falling for circular reasoning in this proof, but I don't have many ideas on what to do other than this.

Comment: Why not just consider a concrete example? Say $f(z)=z$?

Comment: The next exercise is proving that if $f(z)$ is entire in $\mathbb C$, then $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is entire as well, I thought I'd be able to reuse concepts from the proof.

Comment: Perhaps, but when it comes to constructing counterexamples I find it helpful to make things as simple and concrete as I can.

Comment: So you've shown that $g(z) = f(\bar z)$ is *not* complex-differentiable, as you got different limits.

Comment: @TedShifrin The limit are different unless they're zero. But if that happens everywhere, then $f$ is constant and $g$, being constant as well, is holomorphic. So the calculation shows that, for holomorphic $f$, the function $f(\bar z$ is a holomorphic function of $z$ if and only if  $f$ is constant.